# Is there a way to make option statements 'global' in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net option statements exist that tell the compiler to ignore or compel to standards set by the user.

In my example:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit Off
Option Infer On
```

the problem with this is that these statements need to be repeated in every class in order to become active. Is there a way to make these statements active or inactive globally in every class of my project?

Comment: Go to: Project Menu->Proj Name Properties->Compile Tab - Compile Options.  Note that any `Option __` statements in the code file will override the project wide settings for that file.

Comment: @TnTinMn

Thanks for the solution!

Worked perfectly.

Comment: Please don't answer questions in comments

Comment: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VB Defaults so you don't need to write or tinker them anymore.

Comment: `Option Explicit` is `On` by default and you should NEVER EVER turn it `Off`. `Option Strict` is `Off` by default and you should turn it `On` in your current project and, as suggested, in the IDE options so that it is `On` by default for future projects. You should only turn it `Off` when you specifically require late binding and then you should do so at the file level in only those files that specifically require it, using partial classes to keep the code in those files to a minimum. `Option Infer` is `On` by default and is required for anonymous types but you can turn it `Off` if you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Go to: Project Menu->Proj Name Properties->Compile Tab - Compile Options.

> Note that any Option __ statements in the code file will override the project wide settings for that file

<sub>- TnTinMn</sub>